# How to set/get Gtk "Style Properties"

Tags: gtk

How to set gtk "Style Properties" listed in gtk documentation?
like for GtkWidget there are Style Properties:

```
  "separator-height"         gint                  : Read
  "separator-width"          gint                  : Read
```

So how to get and set them? using GTK+ and C.

Thanks, 
PP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example:

```c
gint height, width;
gtk_widget_style_get(widget, "separator-height", &height,
                     "separator-width", &width, NULL);
```

It works like `g_object_get()`. There is no corresponding `gtk_widget_style_set()` though, you have to set them through a RC file, which you load using `gtk_rc_parse()`.
[Here](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/gtk2-Resource-Files.html) is the documentation on RC files.

Just to be clear though, users generally don't like it when you mess with their themes.

Comment: Thanks... one more thing when we use bg_pixmap[NORMAL] = pixmap in rc file where do we keep that image. Is it a normal png,jpg image or it is other formats?

Comment: @ptomato It is ok to modify the style, but you *must* remember to restyle the *entire* UI, otherwise, some user will experience white on white. Also, dead link.