# How to set/remove the relief of a GTK menu bar object from the C API?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk

Is there a C API call to set/remove the relief around a GTK menu bar object? I can't locate it in the documentation. Can this only be done with a style file?

In this picture I've added a border of 5 pixels to the container holding the menu to highlight the relief - can I remove the relief altogether?

[image: Ugly relief around the menu!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is to change the value of the "[shadow-type](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkMenuBar.html#GtkMenuBar--s-shadow-type)" style property of your GtkMenuBar object to [GTK_SHADOW_NONE](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-Standard-Enumerations.html#GtkShadowType).

You may find on stackoverflow more information about [how to change a style property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536825/how-to-set-get-gtk-style-properties).