# Gtk+ Custom Theme Like Winamp

Tags: c, programming-languages, themes, gtk, skin

I want to know Is it Possible to make custom theme ( Skin ) like [Winnamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winamp) have any documentation about it.. or any other way to do this with GTK+ using other language..
Please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: You should really rethink skinning your application, most custom skins just confuse the user and add no real advantage to it - from my personal experience - only chrome/chromium's custom head is worth using it (due to more space for the actual content). So rethink if you really need it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to [make applications start with a defined existing theme](http://urukrama.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/setting-a-custom-gtk-theme-for-specific-applications/), or you can use a [resouce file, which includes all style information](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/gtk-Resource-Files.html)

Similar Qustion: [How to set/get Gtk "Style Properties"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536825/how-to-set-get-gtk-style-properties)