# How to get the control over the selection in a gtk.IconView?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I want to change the opacity or color of a `gtk.IconView` select box (I want actually to make the selection more visible).

I noticed that the `gtk.IconView` widget had style properties `selection-box-alpha` & `selection-box-color` but only accessible for reading.

The `set_select_function()` method of the `gtk.TreeSelection` class would have been useful to do what I want but it's used for a `gtk.TreeView` and I haven't found an equivalent for `gtk.IconView`

So, how can I do to have control over the selection and perform an action when the user select or unselect stuff ?

Edit :
In fact, change the values of `selection-box-alpha` and `selection-box-color` style properties wouldn't be a solution.
I don't really want to change the selection box opacity but the "opacity" of the pixbuf (by compositing with a color).
So, I need an equivalent method of `set_select_function` for a `gtk.IconView` widget.

Comment: Perhaps this question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536825/how-to-set-get-gtk-style-properties

Comment: No, because these properties are read-only and would be useful if I could write them.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the answer there says that you could modify them using the `gtk_rc_parse` function.

Comment: I had actually misunderstood and this question is quite related but in fact it's not a good solution (I've edited my question). Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, we need to replace the `gtk.IconView`'s default cell renderer by `gtk.CellRendererPixbuf` which have `follow-state` property

We replace the default cell renderer by using the `gtk.CellLayout` class which `gtk.IconView` inherits.

```
model = gtk.ListStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING, gtk.gdk.Pixbuf, gobject.TYPE_STRING)
iconview = gtk.IconView(model)

renderer = gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()
renderer.set_property('follow-state', True)
iconview.pack_start(renderer)
iconview.set_attributes(renderer,pixbuf=1)  #pixbuf is the column number corresponding to the pixbuf to render in the model
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to set the pixmap opacity by implementing a custom `gtk.CellRenderer` that draws the pixmap according to the selection state, and replacing the `gtk.IconView`'s default cell renderer with your own.

Comment: Oh yes, the `gtk.CellRendererPixbuf` widget has a `follow-state` property and it've a `gtk.CELL_RENDERER_SELECTED` constant. I'll see what I can do with that. Thanks

Comment: I can't figure out how to replace the `gtk.IconView`'s default cell renderer. Creating custom `gtk.CellRenderer` is explained in [PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq13.045.htp).

If I understand correctly, I need to use my custom `gtk.CellRenderer` in the `gtk.ListStore` (instead of gtk.gdk.Pixbuf ?) but I don't know how and i didn't find any example).
Have you any example ?

Comment: I finally found the answer that is ... easy. I'll post it as a new answer.